# MSBuild properties as variables in VSTS build definitions

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there a way to get my MSBuild properties (from the `.props` file) as variables in a build definitions in Visual Studio Team Services?

I would like it if it has a built-in way but I am ok with an extension.

Comment: can you clarify: you have a props file and you want to extract it to variables? so `<PropertyGroup>PropA</..>` would be available in subsequent build tasks?

Comment: @MartinUllrich, yes I want for example `<PropertyGroup>      <Version>1.0.0</Version></PropertyGroup>` and want to use it in the build definitions as for example: `$(PropertyGroup.Version)` or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by creating an msbuild project (or target in an existing project) that logs messages containing the needed properties in the form of [VSTS logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/3d06df1b5a805f2443e7a584d58381e179a70528/docs/authoring/commands.md). However MSBuild can not "enumerate" defined properties, so this only works for well-known properties - which is probably good to avoid accidental collisions (even environment variables are "properties" inside MSBuild).

Given a sample `some.props` file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>a.package.id</PackageId>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <Description>I am your test project</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And an example `emitvars.proj`:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="some.props" />
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=PackageId]$(PackageId)" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$(Version)" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=Description]$(Description)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This project file can then be "built" in an MSBuild task (or `dotnet msbuild` on linux machines using .NET Core tooling):

[image: MSBuild task]

For demonstration purposes, I added a PowerShell task that uses these variables:

[image: example PowerShell task]

The build then uses the variables in the script as expected. note that the log lines setting the variables might not be displayed in the build log.

[image: build log]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its clear to me what I should do to have it working. When it is successful I will accept you answer. :)

Comment: @MitchelVreman What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @MartinUllrich @starain-MSFT I fixed my issue with a installed extention: [Variables Tasks Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.VariableTasks&targetId=a0d69947-cbad-4c04-83eb-9e08fe68f333). This extention gives me the task: _Set variable with value from XML_ Where I can get my version from the `.props` file with xPath.